# Не переведены кнопки Unwatch Tag и Ignore Tag

Tags: дефект, локализация, метки

При выборе просмотра вопросов по метке присутствуют кнопки Unwatch Tag и Ignore Tag. Нужно перевести.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для первой кнопки сам собой напрашивается вариант "развидеть". :)

Comment: Каким бы веселым не был бы вариант "развидеть", этот перевод не является правильным...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перевод уже выполнен:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуйте почистить кеш.

Comment: Только что появился перевод, хоть ничего и не чистил. Вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 2):

Я вижу вот такие кнопки:

[image: Не отслеживать метку / Игнорировать метку]